# How to check if variable is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I building E-shop and there will be diferent products categories, so each category product can have diferent columns. For example one product have color, other product from other category don't have color.
I want to do when I adding new product for which don't need use color column I want that in show page, this line below will be not displaying (`<strong>Color:</strong>`).

```
<p>
  <strong>Color:</strong>
  <%= @product.color %>
</p>
```

***Product show.html.erb***

```
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @product.name %>
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
    <strong>Description:</strong>
    <%= @product.description %>
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
    <strong>Year of manufacture:</strong>
    <%= @product.year_of_manufacture %>
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
   <strong>Color:</strong>
   <%= @product.color %>
 </p>
```

**Product form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :year_of_manufacture %>
  <%= f.text_field :year_of_manufacture, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :color %>
  <%= f.text_field :color, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: In `@product.color`, `color` is not a variable, it's a method (specifically an attribute reader method). It sounds like what you actually want to know is how to check if a method returns `nil`, in which case the answer is to call `nil?` on the returned value, e.g. `@product.color.nil?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby, you can use `respond_to?` to see if you can call a method on a particular object. There's really no such thing as an "undefined variable" because variables like `@foo` and `@blah` are `nil` by default, and anything that follows a `.` is technically a method in ruby (such as `@product.color`)

Anyway, try this code:

```
<% if @product.respond_to?(:color) && @product.color.present? %>
  <p>
    <strong>Color:</strong>
    <%= @product.color %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working, still prints out <strong>Color:</strong>

Comment: @Kristis if that's the case, then color *is* defined for all of your products but it's just being left blank in some places. i updated my code to fix it- try it again.

Comment: The `respond_to?` part shouldn't be necessary. Either the attribute exists or it doesn't because the schema is out of date. In fact, for ActiveRecord models with a simple attribute `@product.color?` should do just fine.

Comment: @tadman good point, thank you! i went ahead and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

To display that section only if the `color` attribute of your Product record is defined as a non-blank, non-`nil` value:

```
<% if @product.color? %>
  <p>
    <strong>Color:</strong>
    <%= @product.color %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This is equivalent to `@product.color.present?`. ActiveRecord maps database fields to properties automatically, so if you have a `color` column for that model the method *will* exist.